# Ember inFlight Error on delete

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im getting this error and am having trouble debugging it:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` on <Todos.Todo:ember309:29> while in state root.loaded.updated.inFlight.
```

All transactions between ember and my JSON API seem to be working fine, but if alter the state of the todo, by either renaming it or checking it as complete, and then do a delete, I get the error above.

the changes they are persisting, and if I delete a todo without making any changes, that works as well.

Here is some code:

### Route

```
Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('todo');
  }
});
```

### Controller

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    editTodo: function () {
      this.set('isEditing', true);
    },
    acceptChanges: function () {
      this.set('isEditing', false);

      if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get('model.title'))) {
        this.send('removeTodo');
      } else {
        this.get('model').save();
      }
    },
    removeTodo: function () {
      var todo = this.get('model');
      todo.deleteRecord();
      todo.save();
    },
  },

  isEditing: false,
  isCompleted: function(key, value){
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined) {
      // property being used as a getter
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      // property being used as a setter
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

### Adapter

```
Todos.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    defaultSerializer: "Todos/todosREST",

    serialize: function(record, options) {
        var tmp = get(record, 'store').serializerFor(record.constructor.typeKey).serialize(record, options);

        console.log('ser2:', tmp)
    return tmp
  },
    createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record, { includeId: false });

    var tmp = this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey), "POST", { data: data });

    // console.log('createRecord:', tmp, data, record);

    return tmp; 
  },
  updateRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record);

    var id = get(record, 'id');

    var tmp = this.ajax(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), "PUT", { data: data })

    console.log(this.buildURL(type.typeKey, id), "PUT", { data: data })

    return tmp;
  },
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

### Serializer

```
Todos.TodosRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    typeForRoot: function(root) {
    var camelized = Ember.String.camelize(root);

    var tmp = Ember.String.singularize(camelized);

    console.log('Camelized:'. tmp)
    return tmp;
  },
  keyForAttribute: function(attr) {
    return Ember.String.underscore(attr);
  },
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    // client to server
    var json = {};

    record.eachAttribute(function(name) {
      json[serverAttributeName(name)] = record.get(name);
    })

    record.eachRelationship(function(name, relationship) {
      if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {
        json[serverHasManyName(name)] = record.get(name).mapBy('id');
      }
    });

    console.log('options: ', options)
    if (options && options.includeId) {
      json.id = record.get('id');
    }

    return json;
  },
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    // hash should be an empty object, so just extend it    
    Ember.merge(hash, this.serialize(record, options));
  },
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    // server to client
    console.log('in serializer')

    return this._super(store, type, post_payload, id, requestType);
  },
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    // server to client
    console.log(payload, type)
    var todos = payload.objects;
    payload = {todos: todos}    

    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  },
});
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: will you show the delete code?  (or all of it ;) )

Comment: I didn't extend the standard deleteRecord thats available in the RESTSerializer

Comment: The code calling it, and the rest of the controller/route that's manipulating it.  What version of Ember Data also?

Comment: Ember Data Version: v1.0.0-beta.3

Comment: I added some code, please let me know if this is sufficient, thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show me the todo template?

Comment: and output save errors, todo.save().then(function(){}, function(error){console.log(error);});

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43195/discussion-between-dvreed77-and-kingpin2k)